# How to use "$MAKE install" right?

Tags: pi-2, make, rrdtool

I want to install RRDTOOL, there are some builds needed to be installed first as specified [here](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdbuild.en.html).

While trying to install every build in `bash` with a set of commands like these :

`wget http://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/releases/pkg-config-0.23.tar.gz
 gunzip -c pkg-config-0.23.tar.gz | tar xf -
 cd pkg-config-0.23
 ./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR CFLAGS="-O3 -fPIC"
 $MAKE
 $MAKE install`

I get the following message error after `$MAKE install` :

`install: missing file operand
Try 'install --help' for more information`

How to make this right ?

Edit : 
I attached shell log this time with the chnges "$MAKE"-> "make" and "$MAKE install"->"make install", It's seems not working:

`pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/rrdbuild/libxml2-2.6.32 $ make install
Making install in include
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/rrdbuild/libxml2-2.6.32/include'
Making install in libxml
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/rrdbuild/libxml2-2.6.32/include/libxml'
make[3]: Entering directory '/tmp/rrdbuild/libxml2-2.6.32/include/libxml'
make  install-exec-hook
make[4]: Entering directory '/tmp/rrdbuild/libxml2-2.6.32/include/libxml'
/bin/bash ../../mkinstalldirs /opt/rrdtool-1.6.0/include/libxml2/libxml
mkdir -p -- /opt/rrdtool-1.6.0/include/libxml2/libxml
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/rrdtool-1.6.0’: Permission denied
Makefile:562: recipe for target 'install-exec-hook' failed
make[4]: *** [install-exec-hook] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/tmp/rrdbuild/libxml2-2.6.32/include/libxml'
Makefile:512: recipe for target 'install-exec-am' failed
make[3]: *** [install-exec-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/tmp/rrdbuild/libxml2-2.6.32/include/libxml'
Makefile:471: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/rrdbuild/libxml2-2.6.32/include/libxml'
Makefile:322: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/rrdbuild/libxml2-2.6.32/include'
Makefile:1075: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX shells such as `bash` use `$` as a [unary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation) to substitute the value of a named variable.  A gotcha with variables is they don't have to have been declared in any particular context; you won't get an error for referring to `$whatever` even if a variable called `whatever` hasn't been previously declared or defined.  It's just considered *undefined*.  So typing:

```
> $MAKE install
```

is the same as typing

```
> $whatever install
```

Which, presuming `$MAKE` and `$whatever` aren't defined, this is the same as just:

```
> install
```

Which, by coincidence, is a GNU `coreutils` command (i.e., standard on the system).  It operates on files (see `man install` if you care) so

```
install: missing file operand
```

is the output (an error message).

The command you were intended to use here is actually `make`.  The reason `$MAKE` was used instead is sometimes people will have this defined to expand to the name of something that will fulfill the function of `make`.  This is a bit esoteric, because it really assumes you know something about `makefiles`, which are generally written using  variables with specific conventional names to refer to generic tools.  In the context of executing a makefile, `make` has some of them predefined, including `$MAKE`, and whoever wrote that presumably thinks you will recognize that.

Which is pretty presumptuous, since it probably isn't defined in most people's environment.  Anyway, what you should be doing is:

```
> make
> make install
```

Comment: I added shell lines to the question. I did as you said and understood that. but still I think I don't get the things done right. Is it the right way to install RRDTOOL? as the link I provided at the first sentence of my question guides?

Comment: You now have permissions issues due to the destination path of the install.  Either change the permissions of directory into which you want to install, or use `sudo make install`.

Comment: Yes i just got it. Now do I need to go back all the steps in the manual again ? Or there is something the make this "make install" quicker for each build?

Comment: If it was installed into a custom location where there isn't anything else, it's probably split into `bin` and `lib` directories and such.  In that case you can just archive that and copy it to another pi, it should work as long as the same prequisites are installed.

Comment: Ok thanks your answer worked! Still having struggle to instal RRDTOOL but it is not for this question.